# How to find the coordinates for unique elements in a data.frame using R?

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe with 1644948 obs. of  5 variables.

There are 1138 unique values for data[,5]. i want to find the first value of data[,3] and last value of data[,4] for each unique elements in data[,5].

```
data=    sampleID  chr  start  end     mean
        X536827A01   1 2999931 3000071 -0.015
        X536827A01   1 3018277 3018417 -0.015
        X536827A01   1 3036183 3036323 -0.015
        X536827A01   1 3054557 3054697 -0.015
```

Comment: I guess `sampleID` would be another grouping variable..

Comment: Yes. there are 13 different sampleID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the below code, if the start, end values are ordered. `setDT` converts "data.frame" to "data.table".  We group by "mean" and "sampleID" (`by=list(mean, sampleID)]`), and finally get the first value of "start" (`start[1]`) and last value of "end" (`end[.N]`).  Here, `.N` gives the number of rows per each set of unique grouping variable.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[,list(start=start[1], end=end[.N]) , by = list(mean, sampleID)]
```

Or use `unique` and specify the "key" as "mean", and "sampleID" column.  Create a "end" column as the last value of "end" per set of grouping variable.

```
 unique(setDT(data)[, end:=end[.N], key=.(mean, sampleID)])
```

If not ordered, as @Roland mentioned in the comments

```
 setDT(data)[,list(start= min(start), end=max(end)) , 
                                  by = list(mean, sampleID)]
```

Comment: I'm guessing here, but they probably actually want `list(start = min(start), end = max(end))`.

Comment: And please name the `by` parameter. It makes it easier for beginners.

Comment: @DavidArenburg It should be because I lifted it from one of your solutions :-)